# Error "function call missing argument list" - Help point me in the right direction

Tags: c++

Background: Trying to write a simple program to add a comma in a number over 999 using strings.

Compiler: Visual Studio 2012

Issue: I do not understand what the error means, and i do not know where to search to find an answer (everything i have found online has been specific to the code presented)

Outcome: An explanation of the error is trying to tell me or a topic or area to research please.

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include "string.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
string value="1000";
int size = value.size();
switch (size) {
case 1:
    break;
case 2:
    break;
case 3:
    break;
case 4:
    value.resize(size+1);
    value.insert(value.begin+1,',');
        break;
default:
    cout << "I dont know how i got here??" << endl;
    break;
} // end of switch
return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1>i:\programming\comma_placing_in_numbers\comma_placing_in_numbers\comma_placing_in_numbers.cpp(29): error C3867: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::begin': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::begin' to create a pointer to member
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>i:\programming\comma_placing_in_numbers\comma_placing_in_numbers\comma_placing_in_numbers.cpp(29): error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::insert(unsigned int,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'char' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Comment: Also this is the response from the complier

Comment: Error from complier: http://pastebin.com/59kNWybk

Comment: begin is a function.  try value.begin()

Comment: Thank you working fine! But is there a layman translation of that error? So far i am understanding it to mean that a function call is missing the (). Or a site to help with compiler error messages?

Comment: Yes, `begin` is a function, and function calls have to have `( )`. The error message suggests that you have used the name of a function in your code but forgot to put the argument list, i.e. the `( /* maybe stuff in here */ )`

Comment: The error should also have included the line number on which it occurred. If it gives you a line within some boilerplate header code, that's unfortunate ; some compilers will give you a "trace" back of includes to where the line was in your own code that led to that.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I am new to the visual studio world and it is hard deciphering it's messages (I am using to compilers telling me the line)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler explained it pretty well.

```
value.insert(value.begin+1,',');
```

`begin` is a function. It needs a parenthesized list notation `()` to be called.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now, question will the function name always appear after the "::" ?

Comment: @user3474943 There's no `::`, so I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: i:\programming\comma_placing_in_numbers\comma_placing_in_numbers\comma_placing_in_numbers.cpp(29): error C3867: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> **::** begin': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::begin' to create a pointer to member

Comment: `'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> :: begin'` Compiler is just trying to give you more information about which `begin()` you are trying to call. Here it says inside `std` namespace, there is a class `basic_string` inside which there is function `begin` whose call is missing argument list. [Read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#C.2B.2B) about :: which is a scope resolution operator in C++